# How to leave the temporal branch created by "git pull --rebase"?

Tags: git, git-pull

While being in a branch I have executed

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

This have been resulted in some merge conflicts. By opening the files and selecting the needed parts of the code I have resolved the conflicts. Then I have executed `git add` and `git commit`.

Now, when I execute, `git branch`, I see that I am not in the original branch but in a branch named:

```
(no branch, rebasing my_branch_name)
```

The `git status` tells:

```
rebase in progress; onto 5ae1f3d58
You are currently rebasing branch 'my_branch_name' on '7af1d3d38'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

However, when I execute `git rebase --continue`, as suggested, nothing changes. I stills stay in this strange temporal branch. So, how can I go back to my branch and keep changes introduced by the `git pull --rebase` and the manual merge?

Comment: what is the output of `git diff` ?

Comment: rebase doesn't happen in a branch, but in detached HEAD, i.e. not on any branch. `git rebase --continue` should actually continue the rebase (possibly creating a commit for you to conclude the conflicts), if it doesn't it's most likely a bug. Can you post the exact output of `git rebase --continue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `rebase`, the conflict will be listed. You need to solve the conflicts in each file.

Find the conflicted files.

conflict will look like this

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
code from master branch
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
<<<<<<<<< <some_commit_id>
code from your local file
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`
```

Edit that part and keep the code you actually want.

Then in terminal add the files to git using

`git add <file_name>`

After all conflicts get resolved and added to git

run `git rebase --continue`

If you don't want to do any of this and wants old code before rebase, simply run `git rebase --abort`

Comment: Just wanted to say actual flow. He mentioned that after resolve they ran `git add` and `git commit`. If they committed the resolved code separately, there is no use of running `git rebase --continue`

Answer (score 0):

When resolving conflicts in rebase you do not need to run `git commit` before `git rebase --continue`, this is probably the cause of the issue

If you do then `git commit --rebase` will try to commit the change and get confused as nothing has changed.

The easiest option is probably to undo the last commit and then continue

```
git reset HEAD^
git rebase --continue
```

If you ever get too deep into a rebase that goes wrong you can also `git rebase --abort` and try starting over.